# django nested inlines, any workaround?

Tags: python, django, nested, inline

I want to edit a model in admin that has a foreign key to another model that in turn has a foreign key to the base modell:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Role
from .models import Address
from .models import Date
from .models import Person
from .models import Name

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Role)
admin.site.register(Address)
admin.site.register(Date)
#admin.site.register(Name)
#admin.site.register(Person)

class RoleInline(admin.TabularInline):

    model=Role
    extra=3

class NameInline(admin.TabularInline):

    model=Name
    extra=3

class PersonInline(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fieldsets=[
        (None,{'fields': ['mail','firstName','lastName','phoneNumber','streetAdress','zipcode','city']}),
    ]
    inlines = [RoleInline,Name]
    search_fields = ['firstName']

#admin.site.register(Name,NameInline)
admin.site.register(Person,PersonInline)
```

and this is the model:

```
class Role(models.Model):

    role=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    person=models.ForeignKey(Person,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.role

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('role',)

class Name(models.Model):

    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    role=models.ForeignKey(Role,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

class Address(models.Model):

    name=models.ForeignKey(Name,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    street=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    mail=models.EmailField()
    phone=PhoneNumberField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "addreses"

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

class Date(models.Model):

    date=models.DateField()
    location=models.ManyToManyField(Address)
```

the problem is that name is related to role, not directly to person, i.e role has a foreign key to person and name has a foreign key to role, and that has to be added in tha admin page that I am using. 
The nested inlines semes to be missing in django, is there any workaround?

Comment: how is this a problem (please explain) and what do your models look like? (minimal code required to reproduce the issue)

Comment: added the model. The point is that when adding another model to edit by using inline I have to add the foreign key relation to role.

Comment: What's the point of this 'Name" model actually ?

Comment: every person has one or many roles and every role has one or many names, like adam is an artist and also a actor and as a actor he is called "adam the great" and as an artist he is called "adam the artist". does it make sense?

Comment: Well, kind of yes... Hard to tell without knowing the specs and domain model. But then I wonder why Address is associated with `Name` ?

Comment: if you are a owner then your place has an address, if you play on stage, that is also an address